# How do I accurately measure response time from an API POST request

Tags: java, automation, postman, rest-assured

I write code that sends POST requests and waits for RESPONSE from the server.

I need to measure the exact time it takes to process the information on the server (response time).
I noticed that when I send a request to the server, using  **rest assured** the time there is much larger than the time I get through **POSTMAN**

So my question is, how can I measure time most accurately, and be close to the results I get through the POSTMAN

I have been searching the internet for a few days and have not found a solution

Thanks in advance to all the helpers!!!

*****EDIT*****

I use a rest assured library
And I have there the function that does the POST operation for me

```
public static Response postSubTotal (String var_baseURI, String FileLocation){
    RestAssured.baseURI =var_baseURI;
    RequestSpecification request = RestAssured.given();

    // Add a header stating the Request body is a JSON
    request.header("Content-Type", "application/json");

    // Add the Json to the body of the request
    request.body(BaseJSON.getString(FileLocation));

    // Post the request and check the response
    Response response = request.post("/Transaction/SubTotal");


    return response;
```

I need to take out from the response, The exact time .
so how do i use the filter to do this
what i need to send to this function to filter the processing time from the total time so that **I only have the response time left**

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {

}
```

Comment: Postman provides some metrics around network and first byte.  You can check out the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to measure the time spent in the JVM you can use a [Filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) to log this information:

> A filter is an object that performs filtering tasks on either the request to a resource (a servlet or static content), or on the response from a resource, or both.
> Filters perform filtering in the doFilter method. Every Filter has access to a FilterConfig object from which it can obtain its initialization parameters, and a reference to the ServletContext which it can use, for example, to load resources needed for filtering tasks.
> Filters are configured in the deployment descriptor of a web application.
> Examples that have been identified for this design are:
>
> - Authentication Filters
> - **Logging and Auditing Filters**
> - Image conversion Filters
> - Data compression Filters
> - Encryption Filters
> - Tokenizing Filters
> - Filters that trigger resource access events
> - XSL/T filters
> - Mime-type chain Filter

This kind of filter will measure the time between the received request and the built response. It doesn't consider the time spent over the network, that is not directly under your control, because it is influenced by internet connection.

A Filter let you centralize the log of time spent on the server for each incoming request.

---

A basic example of a filter logging the time can be

```
public class LogTimeFilter implements Filter {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
        long before = System.currentTimeMillis();
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        long after = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = after - before;
        // Do what you need with the elapsed time
    }
}
```

Comment: Really thanks for the response!
This seems to be the direction I need to take, but I would love if you could help me and explain to me . How do I filter the time I need( get the time like in postman)
Because from everything I saw on the internet I could not find anything to explain it

Comment: @MichaelYav I updated the answer with a basic example